# Excel importing to c# windows application

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet with more than 10 tables, and I would need to import those tables into a c# windows application.
I started to do the same by trying to import these tables into a datatable in c#.
I am using visual studio community 2013, and when I try to reference the Microsoft office in my project I only get "Microsoft.Office.Core". I am not sure how do I use this in my application to import my excel sheet.

Do I need to have licenced Microsoft Office to import a excel into my application?

Comment: Could you export Excel into CSV (Save As... and select csv from filetype dropdown)? It's very easy to read CSV files in C#.

Comment: You can use Excel file as ODBC source. Another alternative is using EPPlus project: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Another alternative to using MS Office in your .NET application is [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-library/601). Also for your requirement the following example demonstrates how to [create DataTable from Excel sheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-create-datatable-from-excel/503) with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the Excel Interop DLL in the PIA folder:

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15